MySQL ranking showing values on 1
Each gym earns 1 point for each pound lifted across 10 lifts. The results are stored in a (8.0.36 - MySQL Community Server) table called scores
|score_id| gym_id| m_benchpress | m_deadlift | m_overhead | m_farmer | m_squat | w_benchpress | w_deadlift | w_overhead | w_farmer | w_squat | w_total | m_total | total_points


w_total is a stored value generated from the sum of women lifts
m_total is a stored value generated from the sum of men lifts
Total_points is a stored value generated from the sum of all lifts.

I am trying to assign a ranking to each gym passed on the total points accross 10 events uing the below query
SELECT 
    scores.gym_id, 
    rank() OVER (partition by scores.gym_id order by scores.total_points) 
AS `ranking` FROM scores;

When I run this query ranking shows a value of 1 for every row.
gym_id | Ranking
12        1
14        1 
16        1
18        1
20        1
21        1
22        1

I need a result that shows something similar to this.
gym_id | Ranking
12        1
16        2 
18        3
20        4
22        4
21        6
14        7

I already know I can just order it by score and it will mimic. Howver I need to manage ties and display the data in datatables. This means I need ranking as a value. I considered using PHP to create the ranking but am PHP novice learning on the fly and am more comfortable with MYSQL.

Remove partition by scores.gym_id

partition by gym_id means to rank only within each group of rows with the same gym_id. If you want ranks across all rows, you don't need to group.

I did that first then changed it after the ranks did not match the scores. gym_id 13 with a total_score of 2677 ranked 1 while gym_id 16 which has a total_score of 2677 ranked at 19

Actually, thanks. After your comment tried without the partition again and realized the need to add DESC because it ranks in ascending order as the default.

Please add you answer and closed the ticket ... @A.M.Bookdragon
